# Array Indice in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

```
my @someStuff = qw/Hello and 
              welcome/;     
$#someStuff = 0;                

$someStuff[1] = "Joe";

$someStuff[2] = "Rat";

$someStuff[3] = "roll";

$someStuff[5] = "Jimmy";

print $someStuff[5];
```

I don't understand what happens when I assign `$someStuff` to an index that doesn't exist

***OUTPUT_***

```
Jimmy
```

What happens to [4] even though it's not assigned to anything?

The array now looks like qw(Hello Joe Rat roll ? Jimmy) # ? being the placeholder for [4]
Does it get undef?

E: My code is messed up, dont know how to fix, sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, an array will automatically fill empty indexes with [`undef`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/undef.html) when expanded.

Another example is the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array;
$array[10] = 'last';

use Data::Dump;
dd @array;
```

Outputs:

```
(
  undef,
  undef,
  undef,
  undef,
  undef,
  undef,
  undef,
  undef,
  undef,
  undef,
  "last",
)
```

If you want to avoid that type of behavior, just use array operations like [`push`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) to add to the end of an array instead of having to explicitly specify indexes:

```
push @someStuff, qw(Joe Rat roll Jimmy);
```

Comment: when I actually print the array, it goes (Hello Joe Rat roll Jimmy)
I take it "Jimmy" replaces the 4th indice as oppose to leaving a space or printing "undef"

Comment: When interpolated in a string, [`undef`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/undef.html) is treated as an empty string.  To see it one must turn on [`warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) (which you should do no matter what).  Or print out the array using a dumper like [`Data::Dumper`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) or [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) like I demonstrated in the above output.